# Changing a control's value in a particular Tab of a TabStrip

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Basically, I have a multipage for different departments of information called mpageTabsMain.

Inside each page of the multipage is a tabstrip, that contains tabs that represents different people.

What i'm doing for testing right now is using a button click to fill in a textbox's text on my 2nd page of the multipage.

```
mpageTabsMain.Pages(1).TextBox1.Text = "test"
```

However, what this does is it fills in the TextBox1's text for every Tab (person) in the TabStrip.

How do I refer to a particular tab (person)'s control in a TabStrip so that only that one is filled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- 1) You can't have the same control names within a UserForm.
- 2) If you want to handle different controls for each page (e.g. `TextBox1` on page1, `TextBox2` on page2) you should use a **`Multipage` control** and maybe this would be the better choice for your requirements.
- 3) A **`Tabstrip` control** makes sense for pages with a similar or identical layout, but uses **ONE set of controls** only. So if you assign a value to your `TextBox1.Text` property without further conditions
  (i.e. distinguishing between the different kinds of pages) you'll get the same text for the **same `TextBox1` control** independantly of which page you are addressing. Though a `Tabstrip` can possibly 
  facilitate to write comparable code for only a few controls (distinguishing at which page you are), it could be the *harder part* to code.

**Addendum (refers to comment below)**

OK, you are using a `TabStrip` within a `Multipage` and apparently you want to display a tabstrip tab for every person. (BTW, I wouldn't do that, you could just change the tab name dynamically, but that isn't the question).

> There is no more than **one** unique `TextBox1` control in the whole UserForm. As `TextBox1` is a **unique Name**, and instead your long code line it's sufficient to assign a string value via `Me.TextBox1.Text = "test content for Person A"` referring to a current tab view of Person A or `TextBox1.Text = "test content for Person B"` according to another tab view and another tab value. But it's the same `TextBox1` in any case. `Me` stands for the UserForm itself inside the Userform code module. 
>   You only 'fake' the view to this text (control) depending on the tab situation and are responsible to write it back properly or save it according to the actual tab view :-;

Comment: The reason why I was looking at TabStrip Tabs instead of Pages in the first place is because I essentially need to fill in a document that contains information for multiple people.

I have this information stored in a VBA dictionary with each key representing a person. 

If I used a MultiPage control, there is no way for me to fill in each page of a MultiPage with the information, because even if i set up the controls on each page with different variable names VBA does not let you append strings to concatenate variable names in your functions so I cannot use one function to fill every page

Comment: See my edit in above post; hopefully this explains the effect of your code and answers your question. (BTW I don't understand what you mean with the concatenation issue without a code example; but this could be another question)